# Summation Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data which can be used to find the amount of snowfall in a particular month.

```
MONTH    SNOWFALL INDEX
Jan        0.25
Feb        0.1
Mar        0.6
Apr        0.99
May        0.2
Jun        0.2
Jul        0.01
Aug        0.09
Sep        1.0
Oct        0.5
Nov        0.8
Dec        0.39
```

To calculate how much snow falls in each month, I have the following formula:

```
snowfall_amount = (130 - snowfall_index) / 90
```

I want to write a formula which adds up the amount of snowfall between the months of march and april. Normally, I would create a third column and make the formula:

```
=130 - $B2 / 90
```

and then drag that formula down. Then my solution would be:

```
=SUM($C5:$C6)
```

However here **I am looking for a one-cell solution**. Intuitively it seems like this is the job for a Summation but I don't see any way to do that through formulas.

Comment: Just for the record. Is this calculated as `130-B2/90` or `(130-B2)/90`. It's totally different. Maybe it's wise to include a desired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(sum((130-index(B2:B,match(C2,A2:A,0)):index(B2:B,match(D2,A2:A,0)))/90))
```

[image]